# get a unknown file name in different dir, php

Tags: php

Here is my directory structure,

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\..

C:\download\20150923abc.xls  //abc is a random value
```

how can I attach the file `20150923abc.xls` in php?

Also, how to change the filename after I got it?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to provide a download link through PHP? 
or embed it?
or read data from it and show it on your webpage?
How do you know abc is the valid postfix of the filename?

please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the glob ability to find references all files of type .xls and then you can use the file name references as you wish. This sidesteps the issue of you not knowing the specific file name.

```
$files = glob("c:/download/*.xls");
```

This will produce an array of all .xls files with their full filepath. If you wish to rename or attach these files then you can do this using the `glob` reference:

```
rename($files[0], "c:/download/somenewname.xls");
```

etc. Read more at:

[PHP Glob Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

### EDIT:

From Comment below:

```
foreach (glob( $old_folder."*.xls") as $filename) 
{
     $names = explode('/', $filename); 
     $just_file_name = end($names); 
     echo $just_file_name . "----\n"; 
     $new_folder = dirname(FILE)."\\prm\\att\\";
      //rename_win($old_folder, $new_folder); 
     rename($filename, $new_folder.$just_file_name); <== this line changed.
}
unset($filename);
```

To fix the above code in your comment, you need to change the incorrect variables referenced (there was no array `$files[0]`) to the ones used in the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you, I can get the files. But not success in rename.foreach (glob( $old_folder."*.xls") as $filename) {
   $names = explode('/', $filename);
   $just_file_name = end($names);
   echo $just_file_name . "----\n";
   $new_folder = dirname(__FILE__)."\\prm\\att\\";
   //rename_win($old_folder, $new_folder);
   rename($files[0], $new_folder);
}